# Crash in rjindael.cpp, function AESNI_Enc_Block when using RSA keys

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I am new to crypto++ and just follow an example from its cryptest project (test.cpp). I generated both public and private keys using RSA. I try to use the keys, exactly as in the example. It works perfectly well in crypto++ own project and generates unhandled exception in mine. Below is the basic code, which breaks at decryption stage. any suggestions on why?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <core/osrng.h>
#include <core/modes.h>
#include <core/hex.h>
#include <core/files.h>
#include <core/rsa.h>
#include <core/sha.h>
#include <core/cryptlib.h>

#include <iostream>

using namespace CryptoPP;
using namespace std;

static OFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption s_globalRNG;
RandomNumberGenerator & GlobalRNG()
{
    return s_globalRNG;
}

string RSAEncryptString(const char *pubFilename, const char *seed, const char *message)
{
    FileSource pubFile(pubFilename, true, new HexDecoder);
    RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor pub(pubFile);

    RandomPool randPool;

    randPool.IncorporateEntropy((byte *)seed, strlen(seed));

    string result;
    StringSource(message, true, new PK_EncryptorFilter(randPool, pub, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(result))));
    return result;
}

string RSADecryptString(const char *privFilename, const char *ciphertext)
{
    FileSource privFile(privFilename, true, new HexDecoder);
    RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor priv(privFile);

    string result;  
    StringSource(ciphertext, true, new HexDecoder(new PK_DecryptorFilter(GlobalRNG(), priv, new StringSink(result))));
    return result;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    char privFilename[128] = "pri4096";
    char pubFilename[128] = "pub4096";
    char seed[1024] = "seed";
    char message[1024] = "test";

    try
    {
        string ciphertext = RSAEncryptString(pubFilename, seed, message);

        string decrypted = RSADecryptString(privFilename, ciphertext.c_str());
    }
    catch(CryptoPP::Exception &e)
    {
        cout << "\nCryptoPP::Exception caught: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In my project the program breaks at line

```
StringSource(ciphertext, true, new HexDecoder(new PK_DecryptorFilter(GlobalRNG(), priv, new StringSink(result))));
```

And debugger points to rjindael.cpp, function AESNI_Enc_Block, line 1005.

Comment: Usually such libraries need to be initialized.  Maybe you missed that?

Comment: I encourage you to write up the details of how you initialize in an answer below, and self accept, so if someone searches for this they get more help.  You may have to wait before you can self answer.

Comment: @Yakk - Crypto++ does not have an initialization function (I side stepped the "usually needs to be initialized part"). There are two static objects that *can* suffer the [C++ Initialization Order Fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html). We are trying to tame it with [`init_priority`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html) and ordering of object files in the archive. Also see the discussion of [config.h](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Config.h#Recommendations).

Comment: @jww Sure?  However, I thought the solution was that `OFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption` needed initialization before using (and not just construction)?

Comment: @Yakk - *"However, I thought the solution was..."* - Oh, my bad. Sorry for the confusion. I was commenting on initialization, and not the solution to the problem. The solution appears to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by Yakk, I missed initialisation of the variable s_globalRNG. The following code fixes my problem.

```
//just below main()

std::string seed2 = IntToString(time(NULL));
seed2.resize(16);
s_globalRNG.SetKeyWithIV((byte *)seed2.data(), 16, (byte *)seed2.data());
```

thanks a lot!